# How can you access a javascript class property inside of an anonymous function is the same class

Tags: javascript, class, properties, scope

I have a javascript (es2015) class I want to update the values of an array within a function called by $.each.  However in build myarr is undefined.  I assume `this` is within the `each` function is referencing the anonymous function passed to the `each`.  How can I access the class intance of `myarr`?

```
class mycl{
  constructor(){
     this.myarr=[];
  }
  build(d){
    $.each(d,function(d,i){
      let myd = ..... // Do some stuff with the data
      this.myarr.push(myd);      
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `push[myd]` should be `push(myd)`

Comment: bind the class instance in a variable before each like var self=this;

Comment: @jmargolisvt.. thans for the typo correction.

Comment: @AnamulHasan.  Thanks that worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep a reference to the class in a variable like so:

```
class mycl{
  constructor(){
    this.myarr=[];
  }
  build(d){
    const self = this; //keep a reference to the class here and use it to access class attributes.
    $.each(d,function(d,i){
      let myd = ..... // Do some stuff with the data
      self.myarr.push(myd);      
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using bind in the each function? like so :

```
class mycl{

  constructor(){
     this.myarr=[];
  }
  build(d){
    $.each(d,function(d,i){
      let myd = ..... // Do some stuff with the data
      this.myarr.push[myd];      
    }).bind(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a builder function that is a function of Mycl and call that rather than use an anon function.

```
class mycl{
  constructor(){
     this.myarr=[];
  }
  builder(d,i){
      // let myd = ..... // Do some stuff with the data
      this.myarr.push(myd);      
  },
  build(d){ $.each(d,this.builder);  }
}
```